# Designing data model on dynamodb - Choosing the right partition key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Lately I have been exploring DynamoDb. I came across an interesting advice regarding DynamoDB partition key. The general idea is to distibute the work load. I found that,
you generally use user id as partition key so that it is spread across partitions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-uniform-
load.html

In the case of a school system, I was thinking wouldn't the student's department be a better partition key with student id being sort key?

If student id is partition key, wouldn't that make certain partitions not being used at all after 5-6 years once they leave the school given that student id is a sequential number. However, if department is partition key the data is equally distributed if data of people who leave the school is retained.

[image: Sample data with Department name as partition key]

Comment: Are student ids allocated per department? I would expect a student id to be unique within a school rather than department. If my assumption is correct, then without knowing anything about your data access patterns, I'd assume the student id is a better partition key, and conceptually it's what you'd expect. If ids are allocated per department, then I'd expect a partition key of department and SK of student id to make the most sense.

Comment: @404 Student Id is unique sequence within a school. But wouldn't that make older sequence numbers to go to a specific partition and make those partitions to not share load, because they will be very less frequently accessed after they leave the school?

Comment: ok, after exploring a bit more, I understand that the hash function they have would take care of sequential data and ensure even distribution as much as possible even if the partition key is a sequential data.

Comment: @404 While accessing there will always be department id and student id and not just student Id. In such a case does it make a difference ?

Comment: I suppose it could allow you to easily get all students for a department if you set the partition key to department. If you know that you will *always* use both department and student id to look up a student, and you want to be able to look up multiple students for a single department, then it could make sense.